# Python Print Function Fails

Tags: python

I get a syntax error when running this on my Raspberry Pi.  Code was developed on my Mac and runs fine there.  Any ideas what the cause may be?

```
print(f"Updating information {datetime.now().isoformat()}")
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your Python version is not compatible with f-strings.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: f-strings were introduced four and a half years ago in Python 3.6.

Comment: `Beginning with version 3.6, Python has a new type of string - f-string`. You should use python version 3.6+

Comment: Python version 2.7.16.  Same version that's on my Mac

Comment: @HelpMeCode there's your problemo

Comment: Python 2.7 stopped receiving security updates 1 and 1/2 years ago. It was released in 2010 and now is almost never used for new development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3's f-Strings are available only from `python 3.6`

You can follow this gist (https://gist.github.com/dschep/24aa61672a2092246eaca2824400d37f#installing-python-36-on-raspbian) to upgrade and then try the same command